# Why loop in Selenium IDE is not correct?

Tags: loops, selenium-ide

In Selenium IDE I want to make click for each element on the page. So I tried the next commands:

1. here test failed on the click | ${approve[${i}]} |
   `store | css=a[title="Approve"] | approve store | 1 | i while | ${i} <= ${approve.length}  click | ${approve[${i}]} |  store | ${i} + 1 | i`
2. here it cause click only on the first element

execute script | var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[title="Approve"]'); for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {links[i].click(); }

3. it is failed on click | ${element}
   `store | css =a[title="Approve"] | approves for each | element | ${approves} click | ${element} end`

Please help me to find where is the problem. Thanks.